# Determine where in the code a console app in release configuration has hung

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I have run a .NET 5 console application in release configuration on Windows like this:

```
dotnet run -c RELEASE
```

The console app has hung after running for about three hours. Other than restarting the app e.g., in debug configuration or after adding more logging, how, if at all, can I determine where in the code the app has hung.

For instance, is there a way to attach the debugger to an app in Release mode? If not, what tool, if any, will show where the code has become stuck. Even receiving a hint about which class or line of code would be useful.

Comment: Yes, you can attach the debugger to a running process. However if it's in release mode, you won't be able to hit breakpoints. Within Visual Studio, go to `Debug -> Attach to Process` and choose your app. Then hit 'Break' and you might get a stack trace

Comment: This also worked for dumping the stack trace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-stack#dotnet-stack-report

Comment: If it is an unhandled exception you can use EventViewer if you are in windows to see what exactly happened and it will give you where in code and usually the line number it broke on.

Answer (score 1):

Because we are talking about a release, I figured that we are also talking about a actual server that has no Visual Studio installed.

The best way to do it is to user [dotnet-trace tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace). Basically, all you got to do is run this for as long as necessary (paying a 25% or grater performance hit) and when you complete, you will have a report that you can run through [speedscope](https://www.speedscope.app).

Basically, the longer you see a "plato", that's where the infinite loop is

Comment: Will it show the *plato* on a *dialogue* box? :)

Comment: if there's a hang such as a infinite loop, the plato will appear on the report

Comment: Apologies, that was my (failed) attempt at a joke referring to the philosopher, well-known for his [dialogues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato#Themes_of_Plato's_dialogues).